# Iterate over Array of Objects with Conditions

Tags: javascript

My Array of objects looks like this:

```js
const categories = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'level 1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'level 2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'level 3'
}];
```

I want to dynamically iterate over this categories array and output the `name` property as a string, separated with commas **except the first object in the array**

```
const output = 'level 2, level 3';
```

categories could potentially contain several objects.

```js
const categories = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'level 1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'level 2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'level 3'
}, ..., ..., ...];
```

however, it is important that the first object is not outputted

```
const categories = [{id: 1, name: 'level 1'}];
const output = '';
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite trivial

```js
const getNames = arr => arr.map(item => item.name).slice(1).join(", "); // or slice first, map later

const categories1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'level 1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'level 2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'level 3'
}];

const categories2 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'level 1'
}];

console.log("1:", getNames(categories1))
console.log("2:", getNames(categories2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude first element by combining the use of destructing assignment and spread operator

```js
const categories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'level 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'level 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'level 3' }
]

const [first, ...rest] = categories

const res = rest.map(cat => cat.name).join(', ')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in several ways. However, using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is the easiest way.

```
const categories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'level 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'level 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'level 3' }
];

categories.slice(1).map(category => category.name).join(', ');
```

P.S.

- using slice at first will make a new array starting from index 1 (second object)
- using map will fill the new array with the value of "name" properties of all the objects in the array.
- Finally, using join will convert the array to a string that consists of all the values in the array separated with the value you provide between the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const categories = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'level 1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'level 2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'level 3'
}];

const output = categories.reduce((ans, v, i) => {
  return i === 1 ? v.name : (ans + ',' + v.name)
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not only solving the problem, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question. Thus, please [edit] your post to contain an explanation as to *why* this works. Thanks!